# Why is my installaton of ThreeJS inside of laravel not working?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, three.js

First of all I know Laravel is a PHP framework and has nothing to do with the frontend(JavaScript) of my application. BUT laravel provides the possibility of using webpack which if I got things right is for node modules and other javascript stuff..

What I've done so far:

Installed ThreeJS with command:

```
npm install three
```

than executed

```
npm run dev
```

After that I included the Libary in my app.js file in the resources folder of Laravel like this:

```
var THREE = require('three');
```

(I tried including it whitout assinging it to a variable but that seemed not to work so I just did what some google research told me)

Again I ran npm run dev and the Libary was included inside my packed app.js in the public/js/ path of my project. Everything seems to be fine. I included the app.js file inside of my view and also set the script attribute type to module. But now when I try to import threejs via
`import * as THREE from 'three';`

inside my view it says that the module cannot be found. I know I could just copy the contents of ThreeJS inside the node_modules folder to my public path JS folder but I wanted to keep it as a node module. Any Advise?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you doing when saying "when I try to import threejs"? Do you expect the `THREE` variable be globally available? If so, you can do `window.THREE = require('three')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ostap-brehin I tryed to import the module like this:
```import * as THREE from 'three';```
I'm unsure if this is the right way, but when the module was only available in the app.js file the browser console said ```Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined```

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling like super stupid right now but adding a `window.THREE` instead of `var three` fixed the issue somehow.. Thanks for your help and time anyway!

Comment: It's normal, because your code goes through the webpack which is used in laravel-mix. I once thought that it's weird, too.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can instantiate `Three.Js` you have to import the library:

In your `resources\js\app.js`

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

However, it's recommended to create a instance in the component that actually requires it unless you need it globally.

Comment: I adjusted my question, so the error occurs when trying to import three.
Also I'm kinda sure that the app.js is the wrong place to include the import statement because it only tells webpack which modules to include inside the public app.js file.